# Laravel beginner. Html href redirect to a named route

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am relatively new to Laravel so I don't understand well all its features.

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'PageController@index']);
Route::get('/contact', ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'PageController@contact']);
Route::get('/cart', ['as' => 'cart', 'uses' => 'PageController@cart']);
Route::get('/checkout', ['as' => 'checkout', 'uses' => 'PageController@checkout']);
```

now the question is how to redirect from `html` using `blade templates` to the named route:

I tried:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('index') }}">HOME</a></li>
```

but it redirects to `/index` instead of `/`.

What would be the correct solution for redirect using `{{ route('XXXX') }}` ?

Comment: Can you show all your routes, please ?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: you still have the same issue after running `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: this solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: update the answer please

Comment: The answer has been updated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165525/discussion-between-jeune-guerrier-and-kate-cebotari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">HOME</a></li>
```

**UPDATED**

Run the following commands:

1. `php artisan route:clear`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: It's a working solution. Thanks! But is it possible to use the route alias for this? If not, what is its usage?